# How to create a play sound function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sometimes when an error is detected I want my page to play a sound.
I made this javascript, it does not work:

```
function playsound(){
    var obj = document.createElement("audio");
    obj.setAttribute("src", "click.mp3");
    obj.play();
}

if($('#noerrors').css('display') != 'none' ) {
    playsound();

}
```

Why not?

I want to call playsound(); whenever it please me.

When using:

```
if($('#noerrors').css('display') != 'none' ) {
    var obj = document.createElement("audio");
    obj.setAttribute("src", "click.mp3");
    obj.play();

}
```

It works fine. What's the problem of the first script?

Comment: why are you using `get();` before `play()`?

Comment: "it does not work", do you get any errors?

Comment: It's very hard to tell given the information you've provided. The $.get() makes no sense. Can you provide examples in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @SumanBogati , I copied it from a script. Can I delete get(); ?
RobinvdA , Chrome console stays empty. No errors, I just don't hear the sound when using the first script.

Comment: maybe you do play() before that mp3 is totally loaded!

Comment: do you not know what $.get does? [Docs here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: @Liam, removed $.get();. Indeed it made no sense. Still not working though. Maybe MP3 is not fully loaded, how to make the function wait until its loaded?

Comment: Use the [Web Audio API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/)

Comment: take a look on my answer, in DEMO play after load src

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/3Camg/

```
<div id="error_sound"></div>
<span class="click">Test Sound by clicking here</span>

function play_sound()
{
  $('#error_sound').html('<audio src="http://www.intriguing.com/mp/_sounds/hg/dead.wav" id="err_player"></audio>');
  document.getElementById('err_player').play();
}

$('.click').bind('click',play_sound);
```

You cannot call play on jQuery element, but the HTML element that underlies it.

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest you another solution?

Define `<audio>` just once at the beginning, then call `play()` by selecting that tag:

1.Insert this whenever you want, at the end of the `<body>` for example.

```
<audio id="myAudio" src="click.mp3"></audio>
```

2.Then if you have an error, play it or pause otherwise:

```
if($('#noerrors').css('display') != 'none' ) {
   document.getElementById("myAudio").play();
} else {
   document.getElementById("myAudio").pause();
   document.getElementById("myAudio").currentTime = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this solution ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5XQwZ/)):

```
function playsound(){
    var $audioElement = $("<audio id='audioId'/>");
    $audioElement.attr('src', "click.mp3");
    $audioElement[0].load();
    $audioElement[0].play();
}

if($('#noerrors').css('display') != 'none' ) {
    playsound();
}
```

To ensure to play after load:

```
$audioElement.on('canplay canplaythrough', function(){
     $audioElement[0].play();
});
```